# Angular 2 Chosen TypeScript Errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am trying to use ng2-chosen (https://github.com/zouabimourad/ng2-chosen) in my app.

Since the project is inactive since past few months, I am trying to update it to make it compatible with Angular 2 Final release.

I have made the few changes and added ngModule for this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, Host, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, DefaultValueAccessor, NgModel, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

export interface ChosenOptionGroup {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

interface InternalChosenOptionGroup extends ChosenOptionGroup {
    index: number;
}

export interface ChosenOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
    group?: string;
}

class InternalChosenOption implements ChosenOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
    group: string;

    selected: boolean = false;
    labelWithMark: string;
    groupIndex: number;
    groupObject: InternalChosenOptionGroup;
    highlighted: boolean = false;
    focus: boolean = false;

    constructor(value: string, label: string, group: string) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.group = group;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'div.chosen-drop',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="!disableSearch" class="chosen-search">
            <input (blur)="onInputBlur()" (keyup)="onInputKeyup($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" #chosenInput type="text" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <template ngFor #option [ngForOf]="options_" #i="index">
                 <li *ngIf="showGroup(option,i)" class="group-result">{{option.groupObject.label}}</li>
                 <li [class.highlighted]="option.highlighted"
                    [class.result-selected]="isOptionSelected(option)"
                    [class.active-result]="!isOptionSelected(option) || display_selected_options"
                    (mouseover)="highlight(option)"
                    (mouseout)="unHighlight(option)"
                    (mousedown)="selectOption(option)">
                    <span [innerHtml]="getOptionLabel(option)"></span>
                </li>
            </template>
            <li *ngIf="filterMode && options_ == null" class="no-results">{{no_results_text}} "<span>{{inputValue}}</span>"</li>
        </ul>
    `
})
class ChosenDropComponent {

    inputValue: string;

    @Input() public disableSearch = false;
    @Input() public no_results_text;
    @Input() public display_selected_options: boolean = false;
    @Input() public filterMode: boolean = false;

    @Output() public optionSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() public inputKeyUp: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() public inputBlur: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


    @ViewChildren('chosenInput')
    chosenInputQueryList;

    @Input()
    set options(options: Array<InternalChosenOption>) {
        this.options_ = options;
    }

    @Input()
    set groups(groups: Array<InternalChosenOptionGroup>) {
        this.groups_ = groups;
    }

    options_: Array<InternalChosenOption>;

    groups_: Array<InternalChosenOptionGroup>;

    highlightedOption: InternalChosenOption;

    highlight(option: InternalChosenOption) {
        if (this.highlightedOption != null) {
            this.highlightedOption.highlighted = false;
        }
        if (!this.isOptionSelected(option) || this.display_selected_options) {
            option.highlighted = true;
            this.highlightedOption = option;
        }
    }

    unHighlight(option: InternalChosenOption) {
        option.highlighted = false;
    }

    getOptionLabel(option): string {
        if (this.filterMode) {
            return option.labelWithMark;
        } else {
            return option.label;
        }
    }

    selectOption(option) {
        this.optionSelected.emit(option)
    }

    isOptionSelected(option) {
        return option.selected;
    }

    onInputKeyup(value) {
        this.inputKeyUp.emit(value);
    }

    onInputBlur() {
        this.inputValue = null;
        this.inputBlur.emit(true);
    }

    inputFocus() {
        this.chosenInputQueryList.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }

    showGroup(option: InternalChosenOption, i: number) {
        if (option.group != null && option.groupObject != null) {
            if (i == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return this.options_[i - 1].group != option.group;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

abstract class AbstractChosenComponent<T> extends DefaultValueAccessor {

    protected static NO_RESULTS_TEXT_DEFAULT = "No results match";

    protected chosenDropComponent: ChosenDropComponent;

    protected initialValue: T;

    public options_: Array<InternalChosenOption>;

    public dropOptions: Array<InternalChosenOption>;

    groups_: Array<InternalChosenOptionGroup>;

    public chosenContainerActive: boolean = false;

    public chosenWithDrop: boolean = false;

    protected inputValue: string;

    filterMode: boolean;

    constructor(private model: NgModel, private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        super(renderer, el);
        model.valueAccessor = this;
    }

    protected setOptions(options: Array<ChosenOption>) {
        if (options != null) {
            this.options_ = options.map(option => {
                return new InternalChosenOption(option.value, option.label, option.group);
            });
            this.updateOptions();
        }
    }

    protected setGroups(groups: Array<ChosenOptionGroup>) {
        if (groups != null) {
            this.groups_ = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
                let group: ChosenOptionGroup = groups[i];
                this.groups_.push({ value: group.value, label: group.label, index: i });
                this.updateOptions();
            }
        }
    }

    writeValue(value: T): void {
        if (value != null) {
            this.initialValue = value;
            this.updateOptions();
        }
    }

    protected updateOptions() {
        if (this.options_ != null) {
            if (this.initialValue != null) {
                let initialSelection: Array<InternalChosenOption> = [];
                this.options_.forEach((option: InternalChosenOption) => {
                    if (this.isOptionInitiallySelected(option)) {
                        initialSelection.push(option);
                        option.selected = true;
                    } else {
                        option.selected = false;
                    }
                })
                this.initialSelection(initialSelection);
            }

            if (this.groups_ != null) {
                this.options_.forEach((option: InternalChosenOption) => {
                    if (option.group != null) {
                        let optionGroup: InternalChosenOptionGroup = this.groups_.find(group => group.value == option.group);
                        option.groupIndex = optionGroup.index;
                        option.groupObject = optionGroup;
                    } else {
                        option.groupIndex = -1;
                    }
                })
                this.options_.sort((a: InternalChosenOption, b: InternalChosenOption) => a.groupIndex - b.groupIndex);
            }
            this.dropOptions = this.options_;
        }
    }

    protected inputKeyUp(inputValue) {
        this.filterMode = true;
        let dropOptions = null;
        if (inputValue.trim().length > 0) {
            this.options_.forEach((option: InternalChosenOption) => {
                var indexOf = option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase());
                if (indexOf > -1) {
                    let subString = option.label.substring(indexOf, indexOf + inputValue.length);
                    option.labelWithMark = option.label.replace(subString, `<em>${subString}</em>`);
                    if (dropOptions == null) {
                        dropOptions = [];
                    }
                    dropOptions.push(option);
                }
            });
            this.dropOptions = dropOptions;
            this.filterMode = true;
        } else {
            this.dropOptions = this.options_;
            this.filterMode = false;
        }
        this.highlightOption();
    }

    highlightOption() {
        let optionToHighlight = this.getOptionToHighlight();
        if (optionToHighlight != null) {
            this.chosenDropComponent.highlight(optionToHighlight);
        }
    }

    abstract getOptionToHighlight(): InternalChosenOption;

    abstract isOptionInitiallySelected(InternalChosenOption): boolean;

    abstract initialSelection(initialSelection: Array<InternalChosenOption>);

    abstract isSelectionEmpty(): boolean;

    abstract updateModel();

    abstract selectOption(option: InternalChosenOption)

    abstract deselectOption(option: InternalChosenOption, event);

    chosenFocus() {
        if (!this.onChosenFocus()) {
            return;
        }

        this.chosenContainerActive = true;
        this.chosenWithDrop = true;
        this.highlightOption();
    }

    abstract onChosenFocus(): boolean;

    chosenBlur() {
        this.chosenContainerActive = false;
        this.chosenWithDrop = false;
        this.filterMode = false;
        this.onChosenBlur();
    }

    abstract onChosenBlur();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'chosen-single',
    template: `
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single"
        [class.chosen-container-active]="chosenContainerActive"
        [class.chosen-with-drop]="chosenWithDrop">
         <a (click)="chosenFocus(chosenInput)"  class="chosen-single"
               [class.chosen-single-with-deselect]="!isSelectionEmpty() && allow_single_deselect"
               [class.chosen-default]="isSelectionEmpty()">
                <span [ngSwitch]="isSelectionEmpty()">
                    <template [ngSwitchWhen]="true">
                        {{placeholder_text_single}}
                    </template>
                    <template [ngSwitchWhen]="false">
                        {{singleSelectedOption.label}}
                    </template>
                </span>
                <abbr *ngIf="!isSelectionEmpty() && allow_single_deselect"
                    (click)="deselectOption(singleSelectedOption , $event)" class="search-choice-close">
                </abbr>
                <div><b></b></div>
        </a>
        <div class="chosen-drop"
            [disableSearch]="isSearchDisabled()"
            [no_results_text]="no_results_text"
            [display_selected_options]="true"
            [filterMode]="filterMode"
            [options]="dropOptions" [groups]="groups_"
            (optionSelected)="selectOption($event)"
            (inputKeyUp)="inputKeyUp($event)"
            (inputBlur)="chosenBlur()"></div>
    </div>`
})
export class ChosenSingleComponent extends AbstractChosenComponent<string> {

    @Input()
    no_results_text = AbstractChosenComponent.NO_RESULTS_TEXT_DEFAULT;

    @Input()
    allow_single_deselect: boolean = false;

    @Input()
    placeholder_text_single: string = "Select an Option";

    @Input()
    disable_search = false;

    @Input()
    disable_search_threshold: number = 0;

    @Input()
    max_shown_results = null;

    @Input()
    protected set options(options: Array<ChosenOption>) {
        super.setOptions(options);
    }

    @Input()
    protected set groups(groups: Array<ChosenOptionGroup>) {
        super.setGroups(groups);
    }

    @ViewChildren(ChosenDropComponent)
    chosenDropComponentQueryList: QueryList<ChosenDropComponent>;

    singleSelectedOption: InternalChosenOption;

    constructor(private model: NgModel, private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        super(model, el, renderer);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.chosenDropComponent = this.chosenDropComponentQueryList.first;
    }

    isSearchDisabled() {
        return this.disable_search
            || (this.disable_search_threshold != 0 && this.options_ != null && this.options_.length <= this.disable_search_threshold);
    }

    isOptionInitiallySelected(option: InternalChosenOption): boolean {
        return this.initialValue == option.value;
    }

    initialSelection(initialSelection: Array<InternalChosenOption>) {
        if (initialSelection != null && initialSelection.length > 0) {
            this.singleSelectedOption = initialSelection[0];
        }
    }

    isSelectionEmpty(): boolean {
        return this.singleSelectedOption == null;
    }

    updateModel() {
        if (this.singleSelectedOption == null) {
            this.onChange(null);
        } else {
            this.onChange(this.singleSelectedOption.value);
        }
    }

    selectOption(option) {
        this.singleSelectedOption = option;
        option.selected = true;
        this.updateModel();
        this.chosenBlur();
    }

    deselectOption(option, $event) {
        if ($event != null) {
            $event.stopPropagation();
        }
        option.selected = false;
        this.chosenDropComponent.unHighlight(option);
        this.singleSelectedOption = null;
        this.updateModel();
    }

    onChosenFocus(): boolean {
        this.chosenDropComponent.inputFocus();
        return true;
    }

    getOptionToHighlight() {
        if (this.singleSelectedOption != null) {
            return this.singleSelectedOption;
        }
    }

    onChosenBlur() {

    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'chosen-multiple',
    template: `
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi"
        [class.chosen-container-active]="chosenContainerActive"
        [class.chosen-with-drop]="chosenWithDrop">
        <ul class="chosen-choices">
                <template [ngIf]="multipleSelectedOptions != null">
                    <template ngFor #option [ngForOf]="multipleSelectedOptions" #i="index">
                        <li class="search-choice" [class.search-choice-focus]="option.focus" >
                            <span>{{option.label}}</span>
                            <a class="search-choice-close" (click)="deselectOption(option, $event);"></a>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <li class="search-field">
                    <input #chosenInput type="text"
                    [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
                    [class.default]="isSelectionEmpty()"
                    (click)="chosenFocus()"
                    (blur)="chosenBlur()"
                    (keyup)="multipleInputKeyUp($event)"
                    autocomplete="off"/>
                </li>
        </ul>
        <div  class="chosen-drop"
            [disableSearch]="true"
            [no_results_text]="no_results_text"
            [display_selected_options]="false"
            [filterMode]="filterMode"
            [options]="dropOptions" [groups]="groups_"
            (optionSelected)="selectOption($event)"></div>
    </div>
    `
})
export class ChosenMultipleComponent extends AbstractChosenComponent<Array<string>> {

    @Input()
    no_results_text = AbstractChosenComponent.NO_RESULTS_TEXT_DEFAULT;

    @Input()
    placeholder_text_multiple: string = "Select Some Options";

    @Input() public max_shown_results = null;

    @Input() public set options(options: Array<ChosenOption>) {
        super.setOptions(options);
    }

    @Input() public set groups(groups: Array<ChosenOptionGroup>) {
        super.setGroups(groups);
    }

    @Input() public single_backstroke_delete: boolean = true;
    @Input() public max_selected_options: number = null;


    @Output() public maxselected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @ViewChildren(ChosenDropComponent)
    chosenDropComponentQueryList: QueryList<ChosenDropComponent>;

    multipleSelectedOptions: Array<InternalChosenOption>;

    previousInputLength: number = 0;

    selectionCount: number = 0;

    constructor(private model: NgModel, private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        super(model, el, renderer);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.chosenDropComponent = this.chosenDropComponentQueryList.first;
    }

    updateModel() {
        if (this.multipleSelectedOptions != null) {
            this.onChange(this.multipleSelectedOptions.map((option: InternalChosenOption) => option.value));
        } else {
            this.onChange(null);
        }
    }

    isOptionInitiallySelected(option: InternalChosenOption): boolean {
        if (this.initialValue == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.initialValue.find(value => value == option.value) != null;
    }

    initialSelection(initialSelection: Array<InternalChosenOption>) {
        if (initialSelection != null) {
            this.multipleSelectedOptions = initialSelection;
            this.selectionCount = initialSelection.length;
        }
    }

    isSelectionEmpty(): boolean {
        return this.selectionCount == 0;
    }

    selectOption(option) {
        if (option.selected) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.multipleSelectedOptions == null) {
            this.multipleSelectedOptions = [];
        }

        option.selected = true;
        this.multipleSelectedOptions.push(option);
        this.selectionCount++;

        if (this.max_selected_options != null && this.selectionCount == this.max_selected_options) {
            this.maxselected.emit(true);
        }

        this.updateModel();
        this.chosenBlur();
    }

    deselectOption(option, $event) {
        if ($event != null) {
            $event.stopPropagation();
        }
        option.selected = false;
        this.multipleSelectedOptions = this.multipleSelectedOptions.filter((option_: InternalChosenOption) => option_ != option);
        this.selectionCount--;
        this.updateModel();
    }

    onChosenFocus(): boolean {
        if (this.max_selected_options != null && this.selectionCount == this.max_selected_options) {
            return false;
        }
        this.inputValue = null;
        return true;
    }

    onChosenBlur() {
        if (this.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            this.inputValue = this.placeholder_text_multiple;
        } else {
            this.inputValue = null;
        }

        if (this.selectionCount != 0) {
            let lastOption = this.multipleSelectedOptions[this.multipleSelectedOptions.length - 1];
            if (lastOption.focus) {
                if (lastOption.focus) {
                    lastOption.focus = false;
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    multipleInputKeyUp($event) {
        let value = $event.target.value;
        if ($event.keyCode == 8 && this.previousInputLength == 0) {

            if (this.selectionCount == 0) {
                return;
            }

            let lastOption = this.multipleSelectedOptions[this.multipleSelectedOptions.length - 1];

            if (this.single_backstroke_delete || lastOption.focus) {
                this.deselectOption(lastOption, null);
                if (lastOption.focus) {
                    lastOption.focus = false;
                }
                return;
            } else {
                lastOption.focus = true;
            }
        }
        this.chosenDropComponent.inputValue = value;
        this.inputKeyUp(value);
        this.previousInputLength = value.length;
    }

    private focusOnLastSelectedOption(focus: boolean) {
        let lastOption = this.multipleSelectedOptions[this.multipleSelectedOptions.length - 1];
    }

    getOptionToHighlight() {
        let options = this.filterMode ? this.dropOptions : this.options_;
        if (options != null) {
            let firstNonSelectedOption = options.find((option: InternalChosenOption) => !option.selected);
            if (firstNonSelectedOption != null) {
                return firstNonSelectedOption;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and below is my ChosenModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ChosenMultipleComponent } from './chosen.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ChosenMultipleComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ChosenMultipleComponent
    ]
})
export class ChosenModule { }
```

But when I compile it throws below errors:

```
Class 'ChosenSingleComponent' incorrectly extends base class 'AbstractChosenComponent<string>'

Class 'ChosenMultipleComponent' incorrectly extends base class 'AbstractChosenComponent<string[]>'.

Class 'ChosenSingleComponent' incorrectly extends base class 'AbstractChosenComponent<string>'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'model'.   

Class 'ChosenMultipleComponent' incorrectly extends base class 'AbstractChosenComponent<string[]>'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'model'.
```

Can anyone please help me fix this?